# React Native Expo-Location returns Location service unavailable during initial useEffect

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps, geolocation, expo

**Main Problem:**
I am using expo-location in my Android app in order to find the gps coordinates of the user. I have read and used the sample code provided in the expo documentation. My main problem is that, Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({}) returns `Location provider is unavailable. Make sure that location services are enabled.` This is my code below:

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }
      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      console.log(location);
    })();
  }, []);
```

Status returns `granted` but `getCurrentPositionAsync({})` returns an error. I implemented a janky solution by using try-catch blocks and running `getCurrentPositionAsync({})` again in the catch block, which seems to work. This is my code below:

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }
      try {
        var location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      } catch {
        location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      }
      console.log(location);
    })();
  }, []);
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

EDIT: I tried to run the sample code posted in the expo-location documentation using their snack example. Same result. Could this be a problem with my phone/area? I've tested it with two phones, and both return the same error.

Comment: I have a same problem , I think is a problem with permissions for Android 11+; 
Test this: 
let BackgroundPermissions = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
      console.log({BackgroundPermissions: BackgroundPermissions});

Answer (score 0):

I think `location` variable can't log / use directly and this is the way that I retrieve `location`:

```js
let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});

if (status !== 'granted') setErrorMsg('...');

const { coords } = location;

if (coords) {
   const { latitude, longitude } = coords;
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing this with `requestForegroundPermissionsAsync()` instead. It works when I try it with an emulator, but it doesn't work with my Realme G90T, and Mi 10. On my phone, it still returns the same error: Location provider is unavailable. Make sure that location services are enabled.

Comment: that mean the issue is in your location service on your devices. u can check it in device's setting