# expo-location (React-Native) : Location.getCurrentPositionAsync() never returns anything

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm developing a cross platform mobile App.

I'm testing my code on a Android Studio emulator (google pixel 5, api level 30) and i'm using expo version : ~43.0.2 and expo-location version : ~13.0.4

I've already asked for the location permission, and it works. But when I call the following code i log "there" but never "here":

```js
        console.log("there")
        const userLocation = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync()
        console.log("here")
```

Indeed, the function Location.getCurrentPositionAsync() seems locked

A similar issue has been know in the past according to these links:

[React Native Expo-Location returns Location service unavailable during initial useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68955119/react-native-expo-location-returns-location-service-unavailable-during-initial-u)
https://forums.expo.dev/t/getcurrentpositionasync-doesnt-return-any-value-infinity-loading/23643

But it's also the code in the Expo doc :

https://snack.expo.dev/@charliecruzan/expo-map-and-location-example

. Bellow the entire app class :

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import {Text, TextInput, Pressable, View, Alert} from 'react-native';
import * as Location from "expo-location"


export default class App extends React.Component{
    state = {
        errorMessage: "",
        location: {}
    }

    getAddress(){
        return this.state.address
    }

    _getLocation = async ()=>{
        const {status} = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== "granted"){
            console.log("PERMISSION LACK!")
            this.setState({
                errorMessage:"PERMISSION NOT GRANTED"
            });
        }
        console.log("there")
        const userLocation = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();
        console.log("here")
        console.log(JSON.stringify(userLocation))
        this.setState({
            location: userLocation
        })
    }

    render(){
        this._getLocation()

        return (
            <View>
                 <Text>Salut</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

What did i missed?

Comment: Please add the solution in the answer space. Do not edit the solutions into the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `accuracy` and `maximumAge` in parameters with `Location.Accuracy.Highest` and `10000` respectively as shown below:

JavaScript:

```js
const userLocation = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest, maximumAge: 10000});
```

The solution came from [How to use getCurrentPositionAsync
function in expo-location | Tabnine](https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/functions/expo-location/getCurrentPositionAsync).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on my Android simulator despite the `timeout`. It just hangs indefinitely preventing further code to run. It **does** work on actual phones though, so I'm not sure if it's a simulator bug?

Comment: Tried this in my Android simulator. Seems to work for me.

Comment: Still not working in 2023 ..., the location is very random. It works, but sometimes it just get blocked in an infinite waiting. And now it's timeInterval (android only) to set the next time the GPS fetch for a new coordinates. maximumAge is not available.

That's very frustrating, and for the user of my app. I'm forced to save the location in the Storage, and the next time it didn't work, I'm able to make it work with storage value (but that imply the user has to wait a long time before getting the result since I need to wait for this expo function to respond before switching to the storage)

Comment: Random behaviour, sometimes it works and sometimes it goes in an infinite loop, weird

Comment: The param `maximumAge` is no longer valid for `getCurrentPostionAsync` (neither is `timeout` for that matter)

Answer (score 4):

Seems that this issue appears in some sdk expo versions
this was my solution

```
function getCurrentLocation() {
  const timeout = 10000;
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => { reject(new Error(`Error getting gps location after ${(timeout * 2) / 1000} s`)) }, timeout * 2);
    setTimeout(async () => { resolve(await Location.getLastKnownPositionAsync()) }, timeout);
    resolve(await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync());
  });
}
```

to get the location you just have to use

```
await getCurrentLocation()
```

hope this helps

Comment: worked for me on expo sdk 48

Answer (score 0):

If none of the given solutions work you will need to add the required code in `android/build.gradle` file.

```
  configurations.all{
     resolutionStrategy{
        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1"
     }
  }
```

[image]

So what we are doing here is locking google play services version to `21.0.1`.

Answer (score -2):

As explained in this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/s2ja6v/do_location_services_work_in_expo_for_android/), the location service only works in emulators if you are logged into a google account.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).